# Evaluating area of a circle using integration. $\int_{0}^{R} \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals, circles

I became curious about the alternative methods to write a formula for the area of a circle rather than the popular method of dividing a circle into equal sections of an infinitesimal angle.

I gave it a thought and made a little headway.

For a circle, $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$, where $R$ is the radius.

$\therefore y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$

$\int_{0}^{R} \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} dx$ = Area of each quadrant

$\Rightarrow$ Area of circle = $\int_{0}^{R} 4\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} dx$

I can't understand how to start with.

Comment: Make now the change of variable $x=R \sin t$ in your integral $\int_{0}^{1} 4\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}\color{red}{dx}$ (differential element $dx$ is essential).

Comment: @,JeanMarie  Thank you for reminding me. I  forgot to put it.

Comment: Your upper limit should be $R$, not $1$. It's also worth doing in polar coordinates, which write the circle's area as $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^Rrdrd\theta$.

Comment: @J.G. 1) The upper limit has been corrected, thanks to your remark 2) I think advising the use of double integrals for a (likely) young learner is not the best ; one should stick to simple integrals.

Comment: We can integrate $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ with the limits , which will end up with $\sin^{-1}1-\sin^{-1}0 = \pi/2$. We will get $Area = \pi \times 1^2$ when $r = 1$. Check this when we want general value for $r$ : [[ https://homework.study.com/explanation/how-to-integrate-sqrt-1-x-2.html ]] : We will get same $\sin^{-1}(\cdot)$ with $Area = \pi r^2$ in the end !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$I=\int_{0}^{R} \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} dx$$

To compute this, we can use the standard trig-sub, let $x=R\sin\theta$, so $x\in[0, R]\Rightarrow\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2]$. Also, we have $dx=R\cos\theta d\theta$, so the integral is converted to

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \sqrt{R^2 - R^2\sin^2\theta}\cdot R\cos\theta d\theta$$

We use the identity $1-\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta$, and get

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} R\cos\theta\cdot R\cos\theta d\theta=R^2\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} \cos^2\theta ~d\theta$$

Next, we use identity $\cos^2\theta=\frac{1+\cos2\theta}2$

$$I=\frac{1}2R^2\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2} 1+\cos2\theta ~d\theta=\frac{1}2R^2\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}2R^2\cdot\frac12\sin2\theta\bigg|_0^\frac\pi2$$

Note the second term vanishes, hence we get

$$I=\frac14\pi R^2$$

which is the area of a quarter of the circle.

Comment: It was a duplicate.